# "gcloud auth revoke" doesn't work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I need to delete from a machine my Account which has been setted as an Active account in GCLOUD.
I have tried several time `gcloud auth revoke test@gmail.com`  but it doesn't do anything, no error, no execution.
I don't know how to delete my account. I have tried even `gcloud auth revoke --all` but it doesn't work either.
Any idea?

Comment: Try removing (or moving elsewhere, in case you need them back at some point) the gcloud config files related to authentication (or the entire config, if you need). On linux they're in `~/.config/gcloud`. Not sure which file is the right one, tho.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't do anything" how do you know? If you run `gcloud auth list` do you still see account after revoking it? Can you run a gcloud command with `--account test@gmail.com` flag? If this is the case you should run `gcloud feedback` command to report this issue.